# error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file

Tags: c#, wix, wixsharp

Running a `WixSharp Managed Setup` up project I'm getting this error.
Using `WixUI_Common`

```
C:\agent\_work\66\s\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\Common.wxs(7) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file
```

This location `C:\agent\_work\66\s\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\Common.wxs(7)` doesn't locate in my PC.
I have only `C:\` in the above path
I have no clue from where I get it.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Looked like a CI/CD build rather than something you are building on your PC (good info to provide btw), it looks like the Common.wxs file does not exist when the automation is trying to build your project. I'd make sure it exists in your repo for starters.

Comment: @ bschellekens, I'm running the project locally.

Answer (score 0):

what that resolved my issue:
Uninstall all WixSharp libraries from the solution and reinstall them.